# RSpec: testing AR finders without hitting the database

Tags: ruby, rspec, bdd

How would I test the following finder with RSpec?

```
def self.find_by_mbid(mbid)
  super(mbid.downcase())
end
```

The only way I see that is possible would be storing it in the database beforehand, which I'd like to avoid, as this is a unit test. I don't see how to return a mock here, since `super` is pretty much inaccessible to RSpec.

Is there a better way of doing this? Or are unit tests too low-level for this sort of thing?

Comment: Additional comments: Figure out whether you really need this. I've had AR do case-insensitive searches even when the DB does not by default. Also, lose the `()` on the method call; this isn't Java. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You *could* mock this if you're willing to change the implementation, but I recommend spec'ing finders with the database.